I'm trying to use express-validators in a function
Everyone says to use an array but I want to see how to would do it in a function.
I have something like this
const checkPasswordConfirm = () => {
    body('password-confirm').custom((value, { req }) => {
        if(value !== req.body.password) {
            throw new Error('Passwords confirmation does not match password')
        }
    })
}


What is your question?

Here, you need to return true of validation passes
enter code heconst { body } = require('express-validator');

const checkPasswordConfirm = () => {
return body('password-confirm').custom((value, { req }) => {
    if (value !== req.body.password) {
        throw new Error('Password confirmation does not match password');
    }
    return true; // Return true if validation passes
  });
};

module.exports = checkPasswordConfirm;re


thank you! why do you need to return the body('password-confirm)?

Need to return the result of the validation. SO it will either return the boolean or error
